# How to avoid CapsLock key when using shortcut keys of IntelliJ idea on linux

Tags: linux, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ idea on centos with kde desktop.The problem is when I want use the idea shortcut keys, I must hit <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> first.

For example: I want to open the "Find in Path" dialog, if I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, it does not work. I must hit the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> before it.

It is because the keymap of "Find in Path" is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

I can make this works if I edit in keymap setting and add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to this action. But if I want all the similar keymap working, I must edit every action, is there any other ways?

**Update:**
when i use the IntelliJ idea with root user, then it works! with <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> on and off. How can i apply this behavior works with normal user ?

**Update2:**
Sorry,now I find that it is because key conflict: with the Intelligent Pinyin input method enabled , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> not work.Without the Intelligent Pinyin input method, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on your desktop environment (KDE).

I use Mate on Ubuntu, and shortcuts in Idea work in both cases - with <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> on and off.

Try different desktop environment.

Comment: update: when i use the IntelliJ idea with root user, then it works! with CapsLock on and off.